# Mark closure element mutable Swift

Tags: swift

I have 2 structs, first is:

```
struct LineData {

    init (name: String,
          colorValue: String,
          values: [Int]){
        self.name = name
        self.colorValue = colorValue
        self.values = values
    }

    private var cachedMaxValue: Int? = nil
    let name: String
    let colorValue: String
    let values: [Int]

    // describe max value for Y axis for specific Line
    mutating func maxValue() -> Int{
        if let cached = cachedMaxValue {
            return cached
        }
        self.cachedMaxValue = values.max()
        return cachedMaxValue ?? 0
    }
}
```

Second have array of `LineData` structs:

```
struct CharData {

    init(xAxis: XAxis,
         lines: [LineData]){
        self.xAxis = xAxis
        self.lines = lines
    }

    private var cachedMaxValue: Int? = nil

    var xAxis: XAxis
    var lines: [LineData]

    // describe max value for Y axis among lines
    func maxValue() -> Int{

        var maxValues: [Int] = []
        lines.forEach{it in
            maxValues.append(it.maxValue())
        }

        return 0
    }
}
```

Code above not compile, because, of error on method `maxValues` for struct `CharData`. It says `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'it' is a 'let' constant`

What i want is, iterate through an array of lines and among it max values find greater value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since lines is an ordinary array, how about simply:

```
    for i in 0..<lines.count {
        maxValues.append(lines[i].maxValue())
    }
```

perhaps not quite as Swifty, but nothing gets copied. The optimizer ought to give you pretty much the same performance as forEach.

Comment: `for i in lines.indices {`

Answer (score 1):

It's the `it` parameter/object in the forEach that's immutable. Just like the error says: "it is a let". You could probably do something like this:

```
lines.forEach { it in
    var mutableIt = it
    maxValues.append(mutableIt.maxValue())
}
```

It should be noted that this will create a mutable copy of the "it" struct instance.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the caching though. cachedMaxValue is only updated in the (temporary) mutable copy.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Of course, creating all those copies might cause a performance hit with large data sets (I assume that's why you're caching the value in the first place). You might be better off with a different style of `for` loop instead.

Comment: @MartinR You are absolutely correct. It solves the original problem, but with large datasets there might be performance related issues. Depends on the specific use case, I suppose.